# running 3 parallel command prompts in C

Tags: c, command, multiprocessing, prompt

I am writing a program which runs 3 parallel processes, each one receiving commands from the user. But I need to run 3 command prompts, one for every process, and I'm not sure how that's coded in C.

Comment: You mean you need 3 windows for a single program?  The way you do that is platform dependent, which platform are you working with?  Linux?  Windows?

Comment: Sounds like ncurses windows would be easier, otherwise some form of messaging middleware for all three processes to communicate is required.

Comment: I need 3 windows for a single program, running in Linux. I have the interprocess communication figured out, i'm just not sure how to create 3 terminals in code

Answer (score 3):

To get that to work in a single terminal, you have to:

1. Ensure that at most one of the three processes is reading at a time.
2. Ensure that the prompt for the process that is reading is displayed (not the prompt for some other process).
3. Ensure that the user is very alert and aware of what they're typing.

The first two are non-trivial technical problems requiring inter-process coordination (communication).  The last is not soluble.

As a UI design, that sounds extremely ... sub-optimal.

If you use multiple terminals, then the process-level coordination issues go away; each process works with its own terminal window and the system handles the coordination.  The user, though, has to switch between the different windows to enter the correct data now, so you still have problem 3.  As a UI design, that still sounds ... sub-optimal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I can consider the problems solved since the program is for my own use, my main problem is that I don't know how a single program can spawn 3 terminals

Comment: How to create three terminal windows is very platform specific; you will need to specify which platform you are on, and quite possibly which GUI interface you're using (on Linux, for example, the answer may well be different for KDE and Gnome).

Comment: i'm in ubuntu using gnome. do you happen to have any links to refer me to?